# is it possible call one application from another application without app.js

Tags: extjs, extjs4.1, sencha-architect, extjs4.2

Can anybody tell me if it is possible to call one application from another application without app.js? I have two applications, one application wants to integrate another application. The second application should not contain app.js. If the second app contains app.js will it override the first app.js? I want to run the two apps without merging like frame without using frame.

I have the app, when the user clicks some button I need to bring up the second app in the middle portion. The header and footer are the same. Does the second app need app.js or not?

Is this possible, can anybody tell me the way?

Thanks

Comment: What prevents you from doing it?

Comment: @rixo We have two app rixo.We don't want merge the app. we want run the two app in singe app with app.js or without app.js

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Obviously, you won't be able to have two viewports rendered at the same place, but if what you want is to use components, models, etc., of the other app, that's possible. However, that will create a dependency between the apps, kind of "merging" them de facto.

I suppose by `app.js` you essentially refer to `Ext.application(...)`. You need to include the `app.js` for the "parent" application, and configure its loader so it can find the other app's source files (using the [`paths`](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.1/#!/api/Ext.app.Application-cfg-paths) option).

Example:

```
Ext.application({
    name: 'App1'

    ,paths: {
        // Supposing your second application's root namespace is App2, and is 
        // located in the parent directory...
        App2: '../App2/src'
    }
});
```

Comment: I need to use header and footer from first app . need to change the middle part depend on the user selection  from first app or second app.is it possible

Comment: Once you've got access to the apps component, you'll be free to mix them like you want. That will be easy if you apps are strongly Object Oriented, and possibly far less so if they're not.

Comment: whether second app need app.js?

Comment: I'm working on an application which has no app.js, and doesn't use `Ext.application` at all. These are just optional commodities.

Comment: can you tell briefly how to implement using paths with sample example